# (T1.[Service]<>'Air Ambulance') and (T1.Service=Revenue_Tracker_new$.Service)),

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Trying to combine these to two queries. please help

```
Select
count(distinct([Lead Number])) 'Total service given for the day  - ',
sum(Amount) 'Revenue for the Day  - ',
sum([MUrgency Fee]) 'MUshare for the Day  - '
from Revenue_Tracker_new$
where Revenue_Tracker_new$.[From Date (If Long Term)]='2017-10-17'and
Revenue_Tracker_new$.[Service]<>'Air Ambulance'


Select
count(distinct([Lead Number])) 'Total service given for the day  - ',
sum(Amount) 'Revenue for the Day  - ',
sum([MUrgency Fee]) 'MUshare for the Day  - '
from Revenue_Tracker_new$
where Revenue_Tracker_new$.[From Date (If Long Term)]='2017-10-17'and
Revenue_Tracker_new$.[Service]='Air Ambulance'
```

Comment: SQL server 2017

Comment: Put the text `UNION ALL` between the two queries.

Comment: Your question does not contain enough detail. How do you want to combine them? Horizontally? If so, do you want all results, or do you want to remove duplicates? Or perhaps you only want results that appear in both result rests? Or maybe you only want results that are in one result set and not the other?

Comment: In fact....I think the only difference between the queries is <> 'air ambulance' or = 'air ambulance'. This means you can just remove the WHERE clause from the first query, and have a single query! (Assuming you were looking for a horizontal join)

Comment: I need two query result in a row
These are results with two different condition and i need this on a row

Answer (score 0):

remove `service` condition from `where clause`

```
Select
count(distinct([Lead Number])) 'Total service given for the day  - ',
sum(Amount) 'Revenue for the Day  - ',
sum([MUrgency Fee]) 'MUshare for the Day  - '
from Revenue_Tracker_new$
where Revenue_Tracker_new$.[From Date (If Long Term)]='2017-10-17'
```